# c printing the actual content of string

Tags: c, string

I want to print a `string`, which name was contained by another `string`.
My **code** is this:

```
    int i=1;                            //forexample
    char end[9];
    char start[25]="kerdesek[index].";  //my question(kerdes) array 
    if(i==1){
        melyikkerdes='A';
        strcpy(vege,"a_valasz");         //the exact answer(=valasz) i want to
    }                                    //print
    else if(i==2){
        melyikkerdes='B';
        strcpy(vege,"b_valasz");
    }
    else if(i==3){
        melyikkerdes='C';
        strcpy(vege,"c_valasz");
    }
    else{
        melyikkerdes='D';
        strcpy(vege,"d_valasz");
    }
   strcat(end,start);
   printf("%s",start");                //i want to print the value of the
                                       //concatenated string here
```

**My program prints:**

```
kerdesek[index].a_valasz
```

Do you have any solution? .

Comment: Could you add example input and output?

Comment: from my sturct (kerdesek[index].a_valasz) i have to print "apple",
but it only prints the name of the path, not the exact string, that the path contains

Comment: You are using `end` without initializing it.

Comment: i is hard coded to 1, then you concatenate "a_valasz" to "kerdesek[index]." giving your answer, so... it is doing what you are telling it to.

Comment: sry i translated it bad. vege=end

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UQI6wSw


itsted of seeing the answers i see the names of strings that i want to print

Comment: regarding: `strcat(end,start);`  this is trying to insert a 17 character array into a 9 character field.  At execution time the array `end[]` will overflow, resulting in undefined behavior.  After that error, anything could happen.  Also, `end[]` will contain garbage, so it is unknown where a NUL byte will be encountered.  (more undefined behavior)

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can properly diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

C has no way to evalutate the contents of a string as an expression.  You may be able to do what you want with pointers, however:

```
int i=1;                            //forexample
struct kerdesek_type *kelem = &kerdesek[index];
char *string = 0;
if(i==1){
    melyikkerdes='A';
    string = kelem->a_valasz;
}
else if(i==2){
    melyikkerdes='B';
    string = kelem->b_valasz;
}
else if(i==3){
    melyikkerdes='C';
    string = kelem->c_valasz;
}
else{
    melyikkerdes='D';
    string = kelem->d_valasz;
}
printf("%s",string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to print

> kerdesek[index].a_valasz

but rather what is contained in the structure element?
You cannot construct C code as strings at runtime and have them an executable part of your program.

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_RECORDS 2

struct ker
{
    char a_answer[50];
    char b_answer[50];
};

int main()
{
    struct ker questions[MAX_RECORDS] = {{"a_one", "b_one"},{"a_two", "b_two"}};

    char *reply_string = "None";

    int answer_number = 2; //Example
    int question_number = 1; //Example

    switch (answer_number){
        case 1:
            reply_string = questions[question_number].a_answer;
        break;

        case 2:
            reply_string = questions[question_number].b_answer;
        break;

        default:
            reply_string = "None";
        break;
    }

    printf("%s\n", reply_string);

    return 0;
}
```